# Changing a users posts to drafts upon role change

Tags: posts, functions, user-roles

I have a plugin (automatic role changer) Which will give a user a second role of Subscriber, If their subscription ends they lose the role. 
Is there a way to make their posts change from published to draft when this happens?

Thanks

Added if helps not using a plugin and writing a code: A user signs up as Basic. A user subscribes (woocommerce subscription product), They gain a role Subscriber, then if they cancel it goes back to Basic. (they always have the basic role)

I dont know if a script that does upon Subscribing to product id 1122 the role Subscriber is GAINED, upon canceling the role Subscriber is REMOVED
Upon role being REMOVED all posts are DRAFT

Comment: Is https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-automatic-role-changer-for-woocommerce/ the plugin you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, though I am happy to do via code than plugin if need be.